# how can i use angularjs with spring boot and thymeleaf? is there a template project?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

### **how can i use angularjs with spring boot and thymeleaf? is there a template project?**

*i already googled, but i dont found any. please help me!*

my project now using angularjs and simple servlet on serverside. i want replace my server side code with **spring-boot**, but **spring-boot use thymeleaf as default template render engine**. my problem now is  **i cannot use both angularjs with thhymeleaf**. they are not friendly to each other. so anyone knows a solution, or is there a template project use both of theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't use Thymeleaf unless you've added it to your project. If you don't want Thymeleaf, just remove it from your project's pom.

Put your Angular resources in resources/static, and Boot will serve it up by default without any need for Thymeleaf.

Comment: finally, i done it right as you said.